# SQL Server stored procedure complains about missing parameter, but it is being set

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this method:

```
public class StoredProcedureProvider : IStoredProcedureProvider
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public StoredProcedureProvider(IDataConfig config) => _connectionString = config.ConnectionString;

    public T ExecuteScalar<T>(string procedureName, IList<SqlParameter> parameters = null)
    {
        return Execute(procedureName, parameters, (connection, command) =>
        {
            connection.Open();
            var result = command.ExecuteScalar();

            return (T) Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(T));
        });
    }

    public DataSet GetDataSet(string procedureName, IList<SqlParameter> parameters = null)
    {
        return Execute(procedureName, parameters, (connection, command) =>
        {
            var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            var dataSet = new DataSet();

            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
            return dataSet;
        });
    }

    public DataRow GetDataRow(string procedureName, IList<SqlParameter> parameters = null)
    {
        var dataSet = GetDataSet(procedureName, parameters);

        var tables = dataSet.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().ToList();

        if (!tables.Any()) 
             throw new Exception("The DataSet contains not tables");

        var dataRows = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();

        if (!dataRows.Any()) 
             throw new Exception("The DataTable contains no rows");

        var dataRow = dataRows.First();
        return dataRow;
    }

    private static T Execute<T>(string procedureName, IList<SqlParameter> parameters, Func<SqlConnection, SqlCommand, T> returnMethod)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(procedureName, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                if (parameters == null || !parameters.Any()) 
                    return returnMethod(connection, command);

                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

                return returnMethod(connection, command);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I invoke anything with a parameter that is not a string, I get an error:

> Procedure or function 'generalLogonFromSessionID' expects parameter '@sessionID', which was not supplied.

The code I am using to test this is:

```
var dataRow = _storedProcedureProvider.GetDataRow("generalLogonFromSessionID", new List<SqlParameter>
{
    new SqlParameter("@sessionID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, oTokenData.TokenId.Length, oTokenData.TokenId),
    new SqlParameter("@ipAddress", ipAddress)
});
```

But if I use a stored procedure that only accepts string parameters, it works fine.

For example:

```
var dataRow = _storedProcedureProvider.GetDataRow("generalLogon", new List<SqlParameter>
{
    new SqlParameter("@loginName", oTokenData.Update.User.EmailAddress),
    new SqlParameter("@password", bookingType == BookingType.Commercial ? lastName : "password"),
    new SqlParameter("@ipAddress", ipAddress)
});
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Why is the definition of `generalLogonFromSessionID`

Comment: `new SqlParameter("@sessionID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, oTokenData.TokenId.Length, oTokenData.TokenId)` is incorrect. This overload does not set any parameter value. Also, if the parameter is actually a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, the length would be a constant 16, not your variable length, and it does not need to be supplied.

Comment: Hint: have a look at what the docs for the constructor you're calling, because it isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: Also, lest I forget -- it looks like you're reinventing [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), poorly. Would you like to take advantage of existing work? :-)

Comment: @JeroenMostert swear  I hadn't seen your comment when I started writing my edit... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current example is using the wrong constructor overload.

```
public SqlParameter(string parameterName, SqlDbType dbType, int size, string sourceColumn);
```

Update to use the following

```
new SqlParameter("@sessionID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier) {
    Value = oTokenData.TokenId
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You supplied the @session parameter, but I don't see you set any value for it..

```
new SqlParameter("@sessionID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier) { Value = oTokenData.TokenId }
```

Incidentally, totally appreciate that you're trying to make you life easier by creating a class here that does lots of DB donkey work and means your code becomes simpler.. but it still looks easy to make a mistake (like this). Perhaps take a look at Dapper; it would make the code to exec your proc look more like:

```
using (var connection = someSqlConnection)
{
    var result = connection.Execute("generalLogonFromSessionID",
        new {
            sessionID = oTokenData.TokenId, 
            ipAddress = ipAddress
        },
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
    );

    //do something with result
}
```

No affiliation, just think it's an awesome library that is like what you're trying to achieve, but goes further.. No point reinventing the wheel?